# Azure Mobile App OAuth with API Controller

Tags: azure, authentication, oauth, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Using above service with Xamarin form, I have enabled authentication with OAuth (Microsoft and Google) at server level.

Call from Swagger works fine. However I'm getting *401 error* accessing this via the app. This neither works for **TableController** nor **APIController**. I'm not using *EasyTables*. Following is my code.

```
public async Task<bool> AuthenticateAsync()
{
    bool success = false;
    try
    {
        if (user == null)
        {
            user = await ItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync(this, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);

            Constants.MobileToken = user.MobileServiceAuthenticationToken;
        }
        success = true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        CreateAndShowDialog(ex.Message, "Authentication failed");
    }
    return success;
}

public async Task<ObservableCollection<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool syncItems = false)
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Item> items = await itemTable
                .ToEnumerableAsync();

            return new ObservableCollection<Item>(items);
        }
        catch (MobileServiceInvalidOperationException msioe)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Invalid sync operation: {0}", msioe.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"Sync error: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I tried using rest service client, but not sure how to pass the authentication header. As I seen by Swagger, its actually sending via cookie **AppServiceAuthSession**. How should it be done via Xamarin Forms?

```
    public ItemManager(IRestService service)
    {
        restService = service;
    }

    public Task<List<Item>> GetTasksAsync()
    {
        return restService.RefreshDataAsync();
    }
```

I read that the token we must supply as the 'X-ZUMO-AUTH' is not the access token that provider send back to us; it is the token that the mobile service backend sends back. How we suppose to retrieve this token? And I don't see Swagger sending X-Zumo-Auth header.

Following is my Rest Service initialization :

```
    public RestService()
    {


        client = new HttpClient(new LoggingHandler(true));
        client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-access_type", "offline");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-zumo-auth", Constants.MobileToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ZUMO-API-VERSION", "2.0.0");
    }

 public async Task<List<Item>> RefreshDataAsync()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>();
        var uri = new Uri(string.Format(Constants.RestUrl, string.Empty));
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(@"              ERROR {0}", ex.Message);
        }

        return Items;
    }
```

**EDIT**

After enabling the server logging - Azure service is actually throwing **404** error. And this only happens if I enable the custom authorization on the server.

After debugging the code, I notice following difference between authentication handled by both Mobile App vs Swagger :
Mobile App sets the **Authentication Type** as *Federation*, but Swagger is setting it correctly as *microsoftaccount*
[image: Mobile App]
[image: Swagger]

And this makes the ID different as well :

[image: Mobile App]
[image: Swagger]

I must not be passing the token correctly here.

Comment: I would turn on logging on the client and server, following the guide here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps/wiki/Help,-my-app-isn't-working!#log-outgoing-requests-in-your-mobile-client

Comment: @lindydonna-msft after I enable the logging, I get following error


[0:] Request: GET https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/tables/Items?tenantID=1
[0:] HEADERS
[0:] x-access_type:offline
[0:] x-zumo-auth:
[0:] ZUMO-API-VERSION:2.0.0
[0:]     ERROR Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I figured out so far is that I need to pass the header **X-ZUMO-AUTH** with the current user token to make it work.

And handle this header in the API code to make retrieve user details

```
         //Try to retrieve from header if available
        actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("x-zumo-auth", out auth_token);

        if (auth_token !=null)
        {
            try
            {
                string urlPath = string.Concat(new Uri(actionContext.Request.RequestUri, actionContext.Request.GetRequestContext().VirtualPathRoot).AbsoluteUri, ".auth/me");
                var result = Get<List<AzureUserDetail>>(HttpWebRequest.Create(urlPath), auth_token.FirstOrDefault(), null)?.FirstOrDefault();
                userID = result.User_Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Val;
            }
            catch
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotAcceptable);
            }
        }
```